# IIS 7 and URLRewrite - need to rewrite the url on folder to another folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I couldn't find a good example on how to rewrite the url from `www.example.com/Customers/Test` to `www.example.com/Demo/Partner` using `UrlWriter` at IIS.